# change select option in django via javascript

Tags: javascript, django, jquery-chosen

I have the following issue :

**1/ Using Django, I am generating a form containing a set of countries.**

*The form is as follows :*

```
country=forms.CharField(max_length=20
                     , widget=forms.Select(choices=countries)
                     , label=_('Country'))
```

*The generated html is as follows*

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="col-lg-1" for="id_country"> … </label>
   <div class="col-lg-1">
      <select id="id_country" class="chzn-done" name="country" style="display: none;"> … </select>
      <div id="id_country_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 291px;" title=""> 
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**2- I'd like to update the select dynamically using javascript**

The code to update the select is provided below. The option is correctly changed. However, the "id_country_chzn" is not changed. The consequence is that although the option is changed, the value displayed for the end user is not changed. Is there a special trigger required ?

The javascript code to update the option in the select is provided below. Could someone help me if I am missing anything ?

```
town.val('14').trigger('change');
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you manually change select value, you need to trigger the changes as well:

```
$("#id_country").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events

Comment: Hi, I have tried but it didn't change anything on the value displayed for the user. I have tried with $("#id_country").trigger("chosen:updated"); and with $("#id_country_chzn").trigger("chosen:updated");

Comment: Dear all, ok I have now dowloaded the latest version of chosen libraries and it works ! Thanks so much mariodev